# Flutter Shared Preferences Auth FIle

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to write an auth file, with a list of finals with shared preferences values in it. I could import that auth file in my other files and i could get like the name or email without importing shared preferences in every file.

It would probably look way smoother and cleaner.

I thought something like this would have worked but it didn't

```
/// ------------Auth------------ ///
final email = getEmail();

getEmail() async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.getString('email');
}
```

Does anybody have any idea how to do this?

Greetings,
Jente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to use the method in multiple files. The problem with your code is that the `getEmail` method is marked `async` that means it will have to return a `Future`. Think about it like this, when you mark a method as `async` it means it will return something (or finish executing) in the near future. When ? Well you don't know exactly when, so you'll need to get "notified" when the method is "done", that's why you'll use a `Future`. Something like this:

```
Future<String> getEmail() async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.getString('email');
}

class ThisIsTheClassWhereYouWantToUseTheFunction {
   //let's say you have a method in your class called like the one below (it can be any other name)
  void _iNeedTheEmailToPrintIt() {
     //this is the way you can call the method in your classes, this class is just an example.
     getEmail().then((thisIsTheResult){ // here you "register" to get "notifications" when the getEmail method is done.
        print("This is the email $thisIsTheResult");
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: @SJente it was a wrong copy/paste/edit on my side. Check edited answer.

Comment: Ah yes this looks better. And how should i call it in my other files to get the email?

Comment: @SJente The ```SomeRandomClass``` shows how you can call it from other classes. You just need to import the file where the function is added.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't really get you. I import this auth file in my other files. Then i need to call SomeRandomClass i think? But then what?

Comment: @SJente Yeah it might get a bit confusing, I've added some extra comments to the code, maybe they can help you :).

Comment: Ah yeah i got it. Thanks very much for helping out!

Comment: Glad I could help, have fun with flutter ;).

Answer (score 0):

you can define a class `Auth` or much better a `scoped_model`.

Here's a class implementation

```
class Auth {
   get email() {
       final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
       return prefs.getString('email');  
   }

   set email(String em) {
       final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
       pref.setString('email', em);
   }

}

and now you can call it in your widgets :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

1. make dart file (Filename and Class Name ShareUtils)

add follow Code

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class ShareUtils {
  static ShareUtils _instance;
  SharedPreferences ShareSave;

  factory ShareUtils() => _instance ?? new ShareUtils._();

  ShareUtils._();

  void Instatce() async {
    ShareSave = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  Future<bool> set(key, value) async {
    return ShareSave.setString(key, value);
  }

  Future<String> get(key) async {
    return ShareSave.getString(key);
  }
}
```

2.Add main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static ShareUtils shareUtils;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData mainTheme = new ThemeData(
    );  
    shareUtils = new ShareUtils();
    shareUtils.Instatce();
    MaterialApp mainApp = new MaterialApp(
      title: "Your app",
      theme: mainTheme,
      home: new SplashPage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
       "RegisterPage": (BuildContext context) => new RegisterPage(),
       "HomePage": (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(),         
     },
   );
    return mainApp;
  }
}
```

3.SET

```
void UserInfo(code, token) async{
    await MyApp.shareUtils.set("token", token);
    await MyApp.shareUtils.set("code", code);
    await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("HomePage");
}
```

4.GET

```
Future NextPage() async {
MyApp.shareUtils.get("token").then((token) {
  print(token);
  if (token == null || token == "") {
    Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed("RegisterPage");
  } else {
    Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed("HomePage");
  }
});
```

}

Hope to help.